# Awk: Insert line after N lines following the pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I'd like to insert a line at the 3rd line following the pattern. Example: insert the word `z` 3 lines after each match of `a`

From

```
a 
b1
c1
d1


a 
b2
c2
d2

...
```

to

```
a 
b1
c1
z
d1


a 
b2
c2
z
d2

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/a/{c=1} (c++)==4{print "z"} 1' file
a
b1
c1
z
d1


a
b2
c2
z
d2
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {v1=-100} {if ($1=="a") v1=FNR;if (FNR-v1==3) print "z"; print $0}' input_file
```

the script check if record is "a" and set variable to point to the current line. Then it check if current record line minus previous stored line is equal to 3 and print string, then print current line

Answer (score 1):

or `sed` [insert / append](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands):

```bsh
sed '/^a/{n;n;n;i\z
}' FILE
```

```bsh
sed '/^a/{n;n;a\z
}' FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the scriptable editor `ed` for this: globally insert a `z` three lines after matching `/a/`:

```
$ ed -s input-file
g/a/+3i\
z
wq
```

or, as one line:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/a/+3i\' 'z' 'wq' | ed -s input-file
```

The `ed` commands are:

- `g/a/+3i\` -- globally execute the subsequent command, which is: three lines after matching /a/, insert some text. The trailing backslash continues the insert command to the next line.
- `z` -- insert the text `z`. Lacking a trailing backslash, the insert command ends, completing the global execution.
- `wq` -- write the file back to disk and quit.